# Unable to load configuration file in python flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, config

Some variables had to be moved from the main `server.py` in to a configuration file called `config.py`.

Its contents are something like this:

```
class Config(object):
   #All the settings and variables go here
```

In `server.py`, in invoke this file with:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config.py")
```

However, i get this error:

```
werkzeug.utils.ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config.py'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'config' found in '/mnt/io_files/config.py'.
- 'config.py' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: module 'config' has no attribute 'py'
```

I don't know what to do in order to properly invoke this file. In the same directory, i do have a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Remove the `.py` from the line

Comment: @mousetail If i use this instead `app.config.from_object("config.py")`, then it reads nothing from the file.

Comment: Probably need `config.Config`  to get the object

Comment: @mousetail Just tried it but it still failed, just like having ommited the `.py`. It does not read the variables declared in the configuration,

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked eventually (i don't know what was going on previously):

```
#server.py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config")

#config.py
class Config(object):
   
   #String variables go here
```